# perl5 macos Regexp::Grammars install dies on B::Hooks::Parser

Tags: macos, perl, parsing

I am trying to install Damian Conway's cpan Regexp::Grammars on macos.  I made sure to install Xcode (gcc, clang), first ran 'capn upgrade' on the macos perl (which is now 5.30.3), and then tried the naive 'install Regexp::Grammars'.  Alas,

```
cpan[2]> install B::Hooks::Parser                                                                                                                                                            
Running install for module 'B::Hooks::Parser'
  ETHER/B-Hooks-Parser-0.21.tar.gz
  Has already been unwrapped into directory /Users/me/.cpan/build/B-Hooks-Parser-0.21-0
  ETHER/B-Hooks-Parser-0.21.tar.gz
  Has already been prepared
  ETHER/B-Hooks-Parser-0.21.tar.gz
  Could not make: Unknown error
```

which appeared after

```
...many more
cp lib/B/Hooks/Parser.pm blib/lib/B/Hooks/Parser.pm
cp hook_parser.h blib/arch/B/Hooks/Parser/Install/hook_parser.h
Running Mkbootstrap for Parser ()
chmod 644 "Parser.bs"
"/usr/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- Parser.bs blib/arch/auto/B/Hooks/Parser/Parser.bs 644
"/usr/bin/perl" "/System/Library/Perl/5.30/ExtUtils/xsubpp"  -typemap '/System/Library/Perl/5.30/ExtUtils/typemap'  Parser.xs > Parser.xsc
mv Parser.xsc Parser.c
cc -c  -I/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.30/darwin-thread-multi-2level/B/Hooks/OP/Check/Install -g -pipe -DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV -Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration -Os   -DVERSION=\"0.21\" -DXS_VERSION=\"0.21\"  -iwithsysroot "/System/Library/Perl/5.30/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE"   Parser.c
In file included from Parser.xs:16:
./hook_parser.h:5:10: fatal error: 'hook_op_check.h' file not found
#include "hook_op_check.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [Parser.o] Error 1
  ETHER/B-Hooks-Parser-0.21.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- NOT OK

... many more
```

and it failed to install `Regexp::Grammars` .  Regexp::Grammars does seem to install on linux.  easy or hard fix?

Comment: Is dependency B::Hooks::OP::Check properly installed?

Comment: yep.  B::Hooks::OP::Check had compiled well.

Comment: What's in `/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.30/darwin-thread-multi-2level/B/Hooks/OP/Check/Install`?

Comment: What's does `find /System/Library/Perl -name hook_op_check.h` output?

Comment: nada -- apparently, it has migrated to `//Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.30/darwin-thread-multi-2level/B/Hooks/OP/Check/Install/hook_op_check.h` and three other places...

Comment: I think this issue has been reported before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70545688/2173773)